Performance of textSimilarity() from R's text library
I have a large data.frame with about 4 million rows and 2 columns.
The two columns contain long character strings, texts representing recipes.
For each row, I am comparing the similarity of the recipes in column A and column B, using textSimilarity() from the text library in R.
I like the textSimilarity() function, because it uses text embeddings that "comprises values that represent the latent meaning of a word".
Yet, performance is very slow. Are there ways of speeding this up? Or am I coding this wrong? Can/should I set this up in parallel? Can I use my GPU?
Example data - with way shorter texts:
df <- data.frame(
columnA= c("tomato sauce is very tasty to use", "without garlic, this dish is not chinese", "British food is as tasteless as it can get"), 
columnB= c("pizza is the source of life", "a nice xiaolongbao is steamed until it is soft", "braised pork can be very healthy if prepared well")
)

> df
                                     columnA                                           columnB
1          tomato sauce is very tasty to use                       pizza is the source of life
2   without garlic, this dish is not chinese    a nice xiaolongbao is steamed until it is soft
3 British food is as tasteless as it can get braised pork can be very healthy if prepared will

To get the similarity, I use:
df$sim <- textSimilarity(textEmbed(df$columnA)$texts$texts , textEmbed(df$columnB)$texts$texts)

In the current set-up, this process takes days rather than hours. How to speed this up? Parallelization? GPU? Or are there alternatives?

No need to parallelize in R. text::textEmbed() wraps the Python Hugging Face transformers library, which in turn calls torch, written in C++, which uses multiple threads. If you have a GPU use it. This should speed things up (how much depends on the model). The slow step will be generating the embeddings, rather than calculating similarity. The default model is bert-base-uncased. You can probably cut the time in half by using distilbert-base-uncased. This distilbert derivative ...

claims a 24x speed up (paper here) on CPU. However, it seems to use quantization which in my experience requires later versions of torch and transformers than the versions used by text by default (listed here though looks like you can update with text::textrpp_install_virtualenv()). No harm in trying, but honestly if I hit a wall I'd do this in Python, it'll be much easier to update packages and troubleshoot than with an R wrapper around a Python environment.

Thanks, @SamR. Care to write up an answer for the bounty?

Contextual embedding models are computationally expensive
The default model used by the R text package is bert-base-uncased, which has 110m parameters, including a 12 layer feed-forward neural network.
To compare similarity of sentences, each sentence is split into tokens (which are words or parts of words) and each token is represented as a 768-dimensional vector. Then the token vectors from each sentence are aggregated to create a single, 768-dimensional vector to represent that sentence in vector space. The idea is that with decent token (or word) embeddings and a sensible way of aggregating them this representation captures meaning, so similar sentences appear closer together in vector space. You can then calculate the distance between sentence vectors as a measure of their semantic similarity.
The expensive step is creating the token vectors. Unlike older models such as Word2Vec, with BERT the vector representation of each token depends on the context. A canonical example of this is that the representation of the first word in Apple Inc. was founded by Steve Jobs will not be the same as the first word in Apple is my favourite fruit. This is a strength of this family of models. These sentences should not appear close together in vector space. But calculating the representation of each token based on the others around it, and working out which tokens affect the meaning of other tokens, is computationally expensive.
Use a more lightweight context-dependent model
A good way to speed up things a lot without sacrificing too much accuracy is by using a more lightweight model, e.g. distilbert which has 66m parameters and 6 rather than 12 feed-forward neural network layers.
This is still a transformer model. You still get context-specific embeddings with an attention mechanism to appropriately weight each token based on the surrounding ones. With distilled models trained on larger models like BERT, the results tend to be fairly close to the model from which they're derived, and they're much faster:

DistilBERT is a small, fast, cheap and light Transformer model trained by distilling BERT base. It has 40% less parameters than google-bert/bert-base-uncased, runs 60% faster while preserving over 95% of BERT’s performances as measured on the GLUE language understanding benchmark.

Benchmarking the default model
We need a little more text to measure the performance. I'll use the Biomedical Semantic Similarity Estimation System (BIOSSES) dataset of 100 sentence pairs.
# Read in the data
biosses  <- jsonlite::read_json("https://datasets-server.huggingface.co/rows?dataset=biosses&config=default&split=train&offset=0&length=100")
df2  <- data.frame(
    sentence1 = sapply(biosses$rows, \(row) row$row$sentence1),
    sentence2 = sapply(biosses$rows, \(row) row$row$sentence2)
)

# Define function to calculate similarity
get_similarity <- function(model, dat = df2, col1 = "sentence1", col2 = "sentence2") {
    embeds_a <- text::textEmbed(dat[[col1]], model = model)
    embeds_b <- text::textEmbed(dat[[col2]], model = model)

    text::textSimilarity(
        embeds_a$texts$texts,
        embeds_b$texts$texts
    )
}

No need to microbenchmark here as it takes so long (about 16 minutes):
system.time(
    base_result <- get_similarity(model = "bert-base-uncased")
) # 956.136 seconds

Speed of smaller BERT models
Let's try three other BERT derivatives:

DistilBERT.
Bert tiny intel CPU optimized.
DistilBERT distilled.

models <- c(
    "distilbert" = "distilbert-base-uncased",
    "tiny_distilbert" = "muhtasham/bert-tiny-finetuned-finer-139-full-intel-cpu",
    "distilled_distilbert" = "distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad"
)

l <- lapply(models, \(model)
    list(
        time = system.time(x <- get_similarity(model))["elapsed"],
        result = x,
        diff_from_base = abs(base_result - x)
    )
)

To compare the results:
sapply(l, \(x) x$time)
# distilbert.elapsed      tiny_distilbert.elapsed distilled_distilbert.elapsed 
#             622.071                       61.956                      569.000 

So the tiny model is by far the fastest at just over a minute to run, with the other two much slower at around 9-10 mins. All are substantially faster than the base model.
Accuracy of smaller BERT models
Of course, speed is not everything. Let's compare the distribution of similarity scores to the bert-base-uncased scores:
res  <- cbind(sentence = seq(nrow(df2)), data.frame(l)) |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(
        cols = !sentence,
        names_pattern = "(.+)\\.(.+)",
        names_to = c("model", "var")
    ) |>
    tidyr::pivot_wider(
        names_from = var
    )

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(res) +
    geom_density(aes(x = diff_from_base, color = model, fill = model), alpha = 0.2) +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    labs(x = "Absolute difference", title = "Distribution of differences from bert-base-uncased similarity score")


Interestingly, the fastest model also appears to have the closest results to the base model, at least on this task. You may want to do more robust checks with a subset of your actual data to find the optimal trade-off between speed and similarity to BERT (or whatever your gold standard of similarity is).
Other approaches to speeding up this task
Parallel processing
You suggested using parallel processing. This should not speed things up, as under the hood, text::textEmbed() wraps the Python Hugging Face transformers library, which in turn calls the Python torch library, which already multi-threaded by default. When I run this code, CPU utilisation spikes for all cores. You might want to check the same happens on your machine but I suspect it will.
GPU
You suggested using a GPU. If you have one you should use it. This may speed things up significantly, though how much depends on the model. It looks like the way to do this is to call text::textEmbed(..., device = "gpu"). I would not feel completely confident this will work out of the box though. Getting torch to recognise a GPU generally requires specifying the Cuda version during installation. This cannot be done for you from R when you run text::textrpp_initialize(), as it will not know which hardware or drivers you have installed. You might want to enter the Python conda virtual environment created by the R text package and check whether torch.cuda.is_available() == True. If not, see this question for how to find out whether your GPU is compatible with Cuda and if so how to find the compatible torch version.
A note on using R
There is a cost to using R here. I replicated these results in Python and it was about twice as fast again. Each sentence is represented as a 768 dimensional vector. There's some work going on to take the Python list of Torch.tensors representing each sentence, coerce to a numpy array, then pass this to R where ultimately it's stored as a row of a data frame with 768 columns. I suspect that as the size of the data increases, the time spent on translating the vectors from Python to R reduces as a proportion of the total time, but it would certainly be somewhat faster still to do all this in Python.
Nevertheless, if muhtasham/bert-tiny-finetuned-finer-139-full-intel-cpu will do the job and there are benefits to keeping everything in R, hopefully a sixteen-fold speed up is enough to be able to do this.

This is a great and thoughtful answer, @SamR. Many thanks for taking the time to write this up!!

The stringdist function from the stringdist packagae is pretty fast. To get the similarity between two vectors, a and b you do 1 - stringdist(a, b, method = 'jaccard') (since stringdist with the 'jaccard' method gives you the difference between each string on a scale from 0 to 1, so the similarity is 1 minus the distance).
I created a dummy dataset with 4,000,000 records and two string columns and it
library(text)
library(microbenchmark)
# Generate random strings for vectors 'a' and 'b'
set.seed(123)  # Setting seed for reproducibility
num_rows <- 4*10^6
a <- replicate(num_rows, paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))
b <- replicate(num_rows, paste(sample(LETTERS, 10, replace = TRUE), collapse = ""))

# Create the dataframe
df <- data.frame(a, b)
# Add similarity scores
df$similarity <- 1 - stringdist(df$a, df$b, method = "jaccard")


# Test the time by running the similarity test 10 times.
microbenchmark(1 - stringdist(df$a, df$b, method = "jaccard"), times = 10)

On average the similarity test took just 694 microseconds to run on my computer!
You could also use the 'jw' method. Here's a brief example of using 'jw' and 'jaccard' on the same data.
df2 <- data.frame(a = c('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'ghiiiiiii'),
                  b = c('abc', 'ghi', 'gbi', 'gbi'))
df2$similarity_jaccard <- stringdist(df2$a, df2$b, method = "jaccard")
df2$similarity_jw <- 1 - stringdist(df2$a, df2$b, method = 'jw')
print(df2)




Thank you, Dave!! Interesting approach. But maybe I should have clarified that I am looking for similarity in terms of embeddings. That is why the Hugging Face transformers are so appealing to me. Let me edit my question.

where are you getting that textSimilarity function from? I couldn't find the package that it is from.

You can find it here, Dave: https://r-text.org/reference/textSimilarity.html
